# How to set a custom queryset class for Django admin actions?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-admin-actions

In an application I'm building, I've created a series of custom model managers and querysets to have a higher level api.

The problem comes when I execute an admin action. The queryset passed to it seems to be a generic one, and I would like to have access to my custom queryset to be able to use the filtering functions I created in it.

This is the action:

```
def mark_payment_as_sent_action():
    ''' Admin action to mark payment as sent '''

    def mark_payment_as_sent(modeladmin, request, queryset):

        # #####################################################################
        # This is what I currently do
        payments = queryset.filter(status=models.Payment.S_PENDING)

        # This is what I want to do
        payments = queryset.pending()
        # #####################################################################

        # Do stuff with filtered payments

        return HttpResponseRedirect("...")

    mark_payment_as_sent.short_description = "Mark as sent"
    return mark_payment_as_sent
```

These are the custom model manager an query set:

```
class PaymentQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):

    def pending(self):
        return self.filter(status=self.model.S_PENDING)

class PaymentManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

    def get_query_set(self):
        return PaymentQuerySet(self.model)

    def pending(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.get_query_set().pending(*args, **kwargs)
```

And finally the model and admin classes:

```
class Payment(models.Model):

    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=25,
        choices=((S_PENDING, 'Pending'), ...)
    )

    objects = managers.PaymentManager()

@admin.register(models.Payment)
class PaymentsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    actions = (
        admin_actions.mark_payment_as_sent_action(),
    )
```

Any hint on how can I tell Django to use my queryset when calling an admin action?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What about overriding the [get_queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) method?

Comment: Which one? The PaymentsAdmin class?

Comment: Yes. Also, just noticed the get_query_set instead of get_queryset in your manager. That's probably your problem.

Comment: That's probably an issue, thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noamk noted, the problem was the method name. Django renamed the `get_query_set` method to `get_queryset`.

Now it's working petectly.

```
class PaymentQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):

    def pending(self):
        return self.filter(status=self.model.S_PENDING)

class PaymentManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

    def get_queryset(self):
        return PaymentQuerySet(self.model)

    def pending(self):
        return self.get_queryset().pending()
```